# Is not using admin-ajax to ajax submissions okay?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wp-admin, mysql, forms

I am using ajax to a submit a form which inserts data into a table.

php

```
$data = array('full_name' => $_POST['fullname'] , 'email' => $_POST['email'] 
);
$type= array('%s' , '%s'); 
$wpdb->insert( 'email_database', $data,  $type);
```

javascript

```
$(function() {
$('#testform').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
data: $(this).serialize()
 })
.done(function(data){
alert("works");
})
.fail(function(){
 alert("doesn't work"); 
});
});
});
```

html

```
<form method="post" action="" id="testform"> 
 <div class="input-box">
   <input name="fullname">
    <input name="email">

   <input type="submit">
 </div>
```

It's all put on a template page. Seems to work without any issues but is it the right way?

Comment: Well, you've proven that it works, so in that sense it's "right". If you're creating a plugin or theme for distribution, then it's most certainly wrong.

Comment: nah it's for personal use

Comment: but what's wrong if i use it for theme distribution? just to know

Comment: If the API provides a means for doing something, always use the API.

Comment: no it is not ok. writting bad code should never be ok

Comment: ... and the wrong is that it will most likely will not work on any site that takes security seriously, and probably also on multisites

Comment: So should i stick to the admin ajax method? Can someone please post a proper code?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and some of the things are not OK. I suggest you to consider the following:

1.) **Your AJAX endpoint is not protected**

Currently anyone can send requests to your AJAX endpoint and enter data from anywhere, to solve this make use of [WordPress nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

The principle is to create a `nonce` server-side, send the same `nonce`(you either print it into the header and get with `jQuery`, then merge with the data object you are obtaining from the `serialize()` method) from the AJAX call in the data object. The final step is to verify the `nonce` using the method `wp_verify_nonce()` before saving the data and if the `nonce` is invalid simply don't proceed to save the data.

2.) **You need more validation**

As i can see in the code you don't validate any of the `$_POST` array variables. This is a huge problem and you will get a lot of data that is damaged or no sense.

Comment: Will look into the nonce part thanks. Since it was a test run I hadn't put any validation yet

Comment: pointless nonce abuse is the worst thing happening in wordpress development right now

Comment: why do you think it is pointless when everywhere is recommended?